# FontAwesome fails to load for one user running IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, font-awesome

FontAwesome icons are not working for one of my users who runs IE10. Server is IIS 7.5.  I have mime types configured and icons work fine for others running IE10 as well as Chrome.  When the user looks at the traffic via IE developer tool (F12), he can see requests for the .eof, .woff, and .ttf.  All three requests have OK response headers (200), but nothing in the body, and a total size around 260 bytes.  This user is able to see the example icons on the FontAwesome website.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, our user's issue was resolved after a Windows Update.